# How to Allow Other Users to Run My Script in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

1. Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gw_inIKmUZge13v6Q04FJF7GLovv1reHGvVCcL7GvO0/edit?usp=sharing
2. WebApp: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyyD26jyB159v5x7B23mXWrFNfRalWb5OtO_jkalizIYouHr5yJJOLRcfuLj7hbmrxj/exec
3. Script File:

```
function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("RunTimeStamp");
}
function onEdit(e) {

  novemberStart(e);  
  novemberEnd(e);
  novemberWalletStart(e);
  novemberWalletEnd(e);
  decemberStart(e);  
  decemberEnd(e);
  decemberWalletStart(e);
  decemberWalletEnd(e);
}

function novemberStart(e){
    //variables
    var startRow = 6
    var targetColumn1 = 5
    var targetColumn2 = 6
    var targetColumn3 = 7
    var sheetName = "November";

    //get modified row and column
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var col = e.range.getColumn();

    if((col === targetColumn1 || col === targetColumn2 || col === targetColumn3) && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === sheetName) {

      var currentDate = new Date();
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue(currentDate);
      if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).getValue() == "") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).setValue(currentDate);
      } 
    }
}

function novemberEnd(e){
    //variables
    var startRow = 6
    var targetColumn1 = 14
    var targetColumn2 = 15
    var targetColumn3 = 16
    var sheetName = "November";

    //get modified row and column
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var col = e.range.getColumn();

    if((col === targetColumn1 || col === targetColumn2 || col === targetColumn3) && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === sheetName) {

      var currentDate = new Date();
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,13).setValue(currentDate);
      if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,12).getValue() == "") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,12).setValue(currentDate);
      } 
    }
}

function novemberWalletStart(e){
    //variables
    var startRow = 6
    var targetColumn1 = 5
    var targetColumn2 = 6
    var targetColumn3 = 7
    var targetColumn4 = 8
    var targetColumn5 = 9
    var targetColumn6 = 10
    var targetColumn7 = 11
    var targetColumn8 = 12
    var sheetName = "NovemberWallets";

    //get modified row and column
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var col = e.range.getColumn();

    if((col === targetColumn1 || col === targetColumn2 || col === targetColumn3 || col === targetColumn4 || col === targetColumn5 || col === targetColumn6 || col === targetColumn7 || col === targetColumn8) && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === sheetName) {

      var currentDate = new Date();
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue(currentDate);
      if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).getValue() == "") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).setValue(currentDate);
      } 
    }
}

function novemberWalletEnd(e){
    //variables
    var startRow = 6
    var targetColumn1 = 18
    var targetColumn2 = 19
    var targetColumn3 = 20
    var targetColumn4 = 21
    var targetColumn5 = 22
    var targetColumn6 = 23
    var targetColumn7 = 24
    var targetColumn8 = 25
    var sheetName = "NovemberWallets";

    //get modified row and column
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var col = e.range.getColumn();

    if((col === targetColumn1 || col === targetColumn2 || col === targetColumn3 || col === targetColumn4 || col === targetColumn5 || col === targetColumn6 || col === targetColumn7 || col === targetColumn8) && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === sheetName) {

      var currentDate = new Date();
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,17).setValue(currentDate);
      if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,16).getValue() == "") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,16).setValue(currentDate);
      } 
    }
}

function decemberStart(e){
    //variables
    var startRow = 6
    var targetColumn1 = 5
    var targetColumn2 = 6
    var targetColumn3 = 7
    var sheetName = "December";

    //get modified row and column
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var col = e.range.getColumn();

    if((col === targetColumn1 || col === targetColumn2 || col === targetColumn3) && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === sheetName) {

      var currentDate = new Date();
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue(currentDate);
      if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).getValue() == "") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).setValue(currentDate);
      } 
    }
}

function decemberEnd(e){
    //variables
    var startRow = 6
    var targetColumn1 = 14
    var targetColumn2 = 15
    var targetColumn3 = 16
    var sheetName = "December";

    //get modified row and column
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var col = e.range.getColumn();

    if((col === targetColumn1 || col === targetColumn2 || col === targetColumn3) && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === sheetName) {

      var currentDate = new Date();
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,13).setValue(currentDate);
      if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,12).getValue() == "") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,12).setValue(currentDate);
      } 
    }
}

function decemberWalletStart(e){
    //variables
    var startRow = 6
    var targetColumn1 = 5
    var targetColumn2 = 6
    var targetColumn3 = 7
    var targetColumn4 = 8
    var targetColumn5 = 9
    var targetColumn6 = 10
    var targetColumn7 = 11
    var targetColumn8 = 12
    var sheetName = "DecemberWallets";

    //get modified row and column
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var col = e.range.getColumn();

    if((col === targetColumn1 || col === targetColumn2 || col === targetColumn3 || col === targetColumn4 || col === targetColumn5 || col === targetColumn6 || col === targetColumn7 || col === targetColumn8) && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === sheetName) {

      var currentDate = new Date();
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue(currentDate);
      if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).getValue() == "") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).setValue(currentDate);
      } 
    }
}

function decemberWalletEnd(e){
    //variables
    var startRow = 6
    var targetColumn1 = 18
    var targetColumn2 = 19
    var targetColumn3 = 20
    var targetColumn4 = 21
    var targetColumn5 = 22
    var targetColumn6 = 23
    var targetColumn7 = 24
    var targetColumn8 = 25
    var sheetName = "DecemberWallets";

    //get modified row and column
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var col = e.range.getColumn();

    if((col === targetColumn1 || col === targetColumn2 || col === targetColumn3 || col === targetColumn4 || col === targetColumn5 || col === targetColumn6 || col === targetColumn7 || col === targetColumn8) && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === sheetName) {

      var currentDate = new Date();
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,17).setValue(currentDate);
      if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,16).getValue() == "") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,16).setValue(currentDate);
      } 
    }
}
```

4. HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <h3 align="center">
            <font face="Roboto" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:100px">RUN TIMESTAMP</font>
        <br/><br/>
        <button style="background-color:#333333;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:100px;font-weight:bold;border-radius:5px;height:200px;width:800px" id="button">CLICK HERE</button>
        </h3>

      <script>
        document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",runTimeStampScript);
        function runTimeStampScript(){
          google.script.run.onEdit(e);
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Question:

Why can't other users run the script above successfully? I'm a newbie in Google Apps Script, and I'm trying to update the Time Stamp in my Google SpreadSheet whenever a cell is edited. It works perfectly fine with me. However, when I open the spreadsheet using another Google Account with access as an editor to it, click on the web app trigger by going to the URL above, and edit a cell in the columns being checked by the script, the time stamp does not update.

By the way, I don't get the "you do not have permission to do this action" error. It just doesn't work when I try to use it through another Google Account (imitating "other user").

I have read similar questions here and tried their solutions, but I just don't know how to implement them in my spreadsheet successfully.

Comment: I surprised that you think that you can run it because you  shouldn't name a function onEdit and then call it from another  function.  Because it's going to get executed with every edit to the spreadsheet.  You should rename it.

Comment: The e in userClicked is never populate with the onEdit trigger event object.